# Memory leaks detection in Intruments did not work

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, xcode-instruments, memory-graph-debugger

I'm facing some memory leaks here. These classes were retained when pushing <-> popping from particular view controller. `Memory Graph` allows me to see precisely where the classes are.

[image]
[image]

However, when I recorded the app via `Leaks` in `Intruments`. Instead of finding any leaks, I received this warning.

> Recovery Suggestion: Try setting recording mode to "Deferred" and restarting the trace.

[image]

Even if I enabled `Deferred` under Setting -> Recording tab -> tick on `Always use deferred mode`, the warning remained and turned into `The data volume...` like above. I also tried to increase background sampling duration and Kernel tracing maximum, but no luck. In this circumstance, how can I identify leaks throughout the entire app using Intruments? Or just running on simulators around then check it out in Memory Graph.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.